# How do cats shed their fur?

Tags: zoology, hair

Dogs shed their fur twice a year, so I assume this is the same with cats.

What is the mechanism whereby the change in temperature (assuming this is what causes the shedding) leads to the falling off of fur? Is it the same mechanism as balding?

Answer (score 1):

Basic reasons as to why cats shed fur can be found in [this link](http://www.cozycatfurniture.com/cat_newsletters/catnewsletter13.html) and [this link](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/cat-care/shedding). 
An elaborate understanding of shedding in animals including cats can be obtained from [this link](http://www.furminator.com/why-do-dogs-cats-and-rabbits-shed.aspx). Hope that helps.

Comment: It would be extra helpful if you could summarize the content of the links in your response. :)

Comment: I would suggest that he read and get the info he needs and put in any queries later on. I prefer guiding rather than making it too easy

Comment: I would agree if it were only for OP. But what about all the other people who come to Bio.SE to get an answer to this question? For the health of this community, I think having a tiny bit more detail would be a good thing.